# In Discord.js v14 is there a way to get a categories if a category has a channel named ticket-${username}

Tags: discord.js

it gives an error cannot read property children of undefined
code:
if (interaction.guild.channels.cache.find(x => x.id === 1129514191775084574).children.cache.find(x=> x.name === `ticket-${interaction.user.username}`)) {

i want it to run the code inside the if if there is a channel named ticket-${username}
in the 1129514191775084574 category

Answer (score 0):

The id needs to be a string

```js
let Channel = interaction.guild.channels.cache.find(x => x.id === "1129514191775084574").children.cache.find(x=> x.name === `ticket-${interaction.user.username}`)
if (Channel) ...
```

Or you put the category id at the find method

```js
let Channel = interaction.guild.channels.cache.find(x => x.parent.id === "ID_HERE" && x.name === "CHANNEL_NAME_HERE")
```